# how do I paginate streaming mssql nodejs queries?

Tags: node.js, stream

Using the nodejs mssql package I have streaming queries working inside a promise, but I'm trying to figure out how to clean everything up and allow me to generically emit rows when a method is called. ie implement a .next() method or something similar when a stream is passed in, so that I can change how rows are handled without having to reimplement on row, on error, etc for every case where I want to handle data differently.

```
const mssql = require('mssql');
let stream=new mssql.Request(pool)
stream.stream=true;
stream.query(querystring)

//promise handling stream events

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let rowcount=0;
    let rowbuff:object[]=[]
    stream
      .on("row", async (_json:object) => {
        stream.pause();
        rowbuff.push(_json)
        if(rowbuff.length>=buffsize){
          await handleRows(rowbuff);
          rowbuff=[]
        }
        rowcount++;
        stream.resume()
      })
      .on("error", (err:any)=>reject(JSON.stringify(err)))
      .on("done", async () => {
        //process any remaining rows in SERIAL
        await handleRows(rowbuff);
        rowbuff=[]
      });
  });
```